# How to save an image (path) within my app?

Tags: ios, file, swift, ios8

I want to make an app, where the user fills out some kind of form, and attaches an image to it. The user picks a picture form the gallery (using UIImagePickerController). I already know how to display the image on the screen with `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage`.

I want to make a file which will be used next time the app is opened, so the same image can be displayed with the notes. So preferably I want to save the path to the file so the next time I simply open it with `UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)`. How can I get this path?

Some not so interesting code I have so far:

```
@IBAction func chooseFromGallery(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    
    self.image.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage  // This works
    self.imagePath =  // What goes here?
    println(self.imagePath)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

## Edit

After some reading I found out that there is no way of getting the path to an image which is saved outside the applications sandbox. So everybody looking for the same thing, stop, and use `Bluehound`s answer.
For more information about how files are handled in iOS (and OS X) read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: What kind of code did you use in the end? I am facing the same issue? I like to store the image name in core data and have the images in the same folder or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to store images is the documents directory. You can save to it and then retrieve images from it. I use these UIImage extensions for saving and retrieving images:

```
extension UIImage {
func save(fileName: String, type: String) {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

        if type.lowercaseString == "png" {
            let path = "\(documentsPath)/\(fileName).\(type)"
            UIImagePNGRepresentation(self).writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
        } else if type.lowercaseString == "jpg" {
            let path = "\(documentsPath)/\(fileName).\(type)"
            UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0).writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
        } else {

        }
    }

convenience init?(fileName: String, type: String) {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let path = "\(documentsPath)\(fileName).\(type)"
        self.init(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
}
```

Using this, I can store a file name rather than the entire path of an image using some data storing method such as Core Data.

Use:

```
someImage.save("SomeName" , type: "png")

if let image = UIImage(fileName: "SomeName", type: "png") {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess you didn't understand my question. Say the image is already saved, the user chose it via UIImagePickerController. Now how do I get the path for that image? Your methods get a file path, but that is exactly what my question is about - How do I get the file path?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only get the image data from `imagePickerController(picker:, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:)` so you must cache the image and then retrieve it so you must create the path and you must read from the path.

Comment: Well, do you know how I get that path? (See my code for a way without the path)

Comment: You save the image to whichever path you desire and by saving it, you now have a path reference to it.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use the existing copy? Seems kind wastefull to save another copy of the image.

Comment: Thanks -- Now I understand that what I wanted to do originally is impossible.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate and redundant but that's the way it is

Comment: Suppose the image does not needed unless something has been carried out in another view controller, how can we make sure that the image does not exist forever?

Answer (score 0):

Here is How you can save your image

```
- (IBAction)saveImage {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
UIImage *image = imageView.image; // imageView is where you are displaying image after selecting one from UIImagePicker
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

}
```

You may fetch back this image like this

```
- (IBAction)getImage {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];

}
```

Update :

I believe that you title for question implies a bit differently. Coming back to your question, If you are planning to use only one image all the time, you can have a single image name and use it. This will override the earlier saved image at all times.

Else another option could be creating a simple plist or db and use the image along with timestamp to uniquely identify each image.

Swift Code to Save Image:

```
let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true) {
if paths.count > 0 {
    if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
        let image = ***YOUR IMAGE***
        let writePath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image2.png") 
        UIImagePNGRepresentation(image).writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true)
    }
  }
}
```

To get the image can be very easliy relate from the same

Comment: I think you also didn't understand my question. The question is "How do I get the path of an existing image?" - Also I would appreciate Swift code. :)

Comment: You are right about the question name. Still your solution is not what I need, because I don't know the path, while your code assumes to know the path.

Comment: How is it that you don't know the path of the image? You yourself would be saving the image to documents directory

Comment: `.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image2.png")` is the path  where image is stored. The next time you save another image using same code the earlier one will be replaced. Hence the path remains same but image changes whenever you save a new image. This is as simple as I can put it

Comment: Thanks, after some reading I understood that what I asked for is not possible. This makes your answer a good one. :)