# Set background of another view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, background

I'd like to let the user chose a background for the main view of the app. 
I'd like to know how I can do that for another view, even if the app is killed.

I thought about saving the path of the image in `Userdefaults` and then get it from the main view, but I'm not able to set the background from an `asset URL`. Is there a way to do this ? Or a better way maybe ?

Here is what I've done so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func background(_ sender: Any) {
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum

    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL
        UserDefaults.standard.set(imageUrl, forKey: "background")
        imageView.image = pickedImage

    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How about saving image data to `CoreData`

Comment: @sCha Don't know how to use `CoreData`... 
Never used that.

Answer (score 3):

How about loading URL from defaults in viewDidLoad() and then call setImageFromURL? Of course you have to set the image to your ImageView

```
func setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl url: String){

      if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
         if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: In fact... I think I've a problem with the URL. It find nothing (`nil`) when looking for the URL I have.

Comment: @Hawkydoky maybe you've to allow ArbitraryLoads in your ProjectSettings. (not recommended if you want to publish your app)

Comment: @Moritz the example handles a local URL. In my opinion no need for URLSession

Comment: @chris.breezy Right. I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: finally, i used this answer to get me through this. Thanks for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685943/5385397